# Bluetooth gaming on Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, android-networking, wireless

How can I play bluetooth chess with my iPhone and my friend's Android device? Api? (Probably duplicate of other questions)

Comment: What is range(in meters or feet) you wish your app to work?

Comment: Use Bonjour, Networking and GameKit

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Note that the question specifically includes Android.

Answer (score 1):

[ZeroConf](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) a.k.a. [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002445-SW1) is a fine way to discover other devices providing services, and it's limited to the local network. One of its best features is that it doesn't require any prior knowledge or setup -- it's mission is *service discovery*.

Comment: @Can you shed some more light on ZeroConf stuff or a link to the  brief.

Comment: @blackcrow I've added links to a zeroconf library that's designed for use with Android as well as introductory documentation for Bonjour (which is just Apple's name for the same thing). I think that's sufficient -- if necessary I expect the OP will be able to find [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) without too much trouble.

Comment: This may work for users on the same IP network but... would it work over Bluetooth across device types? (Android Vs iOS)

Comment: @Maroloccio I know that Bonjour works over bluetooth under iOS (here's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) to that effect). Since both standards (bluetooth and zeroconf/Bonjour) are available on both platforms, it should be possible to do the same on Android, but I haven't looked into whether there's support for that in the library at the link in my answer. You could always start by supporting only WiFi connections and then graduate to bluetooth in the future.

Comment: I think Bonjour is fine, but it doesn't really address the issue because it is at a higher level: it is great for discovering services for devices that already share a network.

Comment: @Tom That's true. It also doesn't work well if, say, the devices are switched off or in airplane mode. I think it's reasonable to assume some level of commonality.

Comment: @Caleb, more then that, it assumes that they have some sort of network connection, but the problem is about how to find the nearby devices and establish a network connection to them.  I believe that everything required can be done via Bluetooth on Android, but I doubt it is possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a web service? It'd be easier than doing bluetooth discovery and pairing or wifi-server client stuff (trust me, at least on the latter). It's the easiest way to make everything relatively network (ie 3g/4g/wifi) independent. You just have a simple protocol your app follows, and you can play with all players everywhere, no discovery needed. Probably less battery drain than bluetooth too.

Bonjour is great for discovering stuff (ie other players) on the same network. The problem with bonjour is you usually need to be on the same wifi network (though not necessarily, but don't ask me how the hell this works, but it can be done apparently). You'd also in theory need to apply for an bonjour/mdns id, though this is pretty easy.

Here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210835/is-it-possible-to-connect-two-ios-devices-using-sockets-by-getting-their-ip-addr/10436974#10436974).

Comment: I agree that it would be easier with an intermediary web service but keeping servers online costs and under heavy use the whole thing could end up losing money. Asking users to pay for the game match-up service and fund it that way would not work for this project.

Answer (score 0):

The Following Link Provides a Book Named  "**Beginning IOS Game Center and Game Kit: For IPhone, IPad and IPod Touch**" Hope this Will Help.Best of luck.

[http://books.google.co.in/books?id=C9xVXg3w-LcC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=gamekit+for+networking+in+ios&source=bl&ots=tcO-uKk5ZC&sig=g4ft4nUBep40NCHj9skyLK6fWJQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hPWzT6_TGY2zrAe-jMmADA&sqi=2&ved=0CGIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=gamekit%20for%20networking%20in%20ios&f=](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=C9xVXg3w-LcC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=gamekit%20for%20networking%20in%20ios&source=bl&ots=tcO-uKk5ZC&sig=g4ft4nUBep40NCHj9skyLK6fWJQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hPWzT6_TGY2zrAe-jMmADA&sqi=2&ved=0CGIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=gamekit%20for%20networking%20in%20ios&f=false)false

Comment: It should rather be a comment.